# What method conversion has been applied to this example?

Tags: scala, methods

In the spec of scala 6.26.2, there are 4 kind of conversions for methods:

> MethodConversions
>
> The following four implicit conversions can be applied to methods which are not applied to some argument list.
>
> 1. **Evaluation**. A parameterless method m of type => T is always converted to type T by evaluating the expression to which m is bound.
> 2. **Implicit Application**. If the method takes only implicit parameters, implicit argu- ments are passed following the rules of §7.2.
> 3. **Eta Expansion**. Otherwise, if the method is not a constructor, and the expected type pt is a function type (Ts′) ⇒ T′, eta-expansion (§6.26.5) is performed on the expression e.
> 4. **Empty Application**. Otherwise, if e has method type ()T , it is implicitly applied to the empty argument list, yielding e().

Some scala code:

```
def hello(): String = "abc"

def world1(s: String) = s
def world2(s: => String) = s
def world3(s: () => String) = s

world1(hello)
world2(hello)
world3(hello)
```

My question is, for `world1`, `world2` and `world3`, which conversion rule is applied to each of them?

Answer (score 3):

```
def world1(s: String) = s
world1(hello)
```

Empty application: `hello` is evaluated as `hello()` and then passed as the argument of `world1`

---

```
def world2(s: => String) = s
world2(hello)
```

Eta-expansion + Evaluation: `hello` is expanded into a function and evaluated lazily.

---

```
def world3(s: () => String) = s
world3(hello)
```

Eta-expansion: `hello` is expanded to a `Function0[String]`

---

Eta-expansion is necessary because methods and functions are two different things, even though the scala compiler is very good at hiding this difference.

The difference comes from the fact that methods are a JVM concept, whereas first-class functions are a scala-specific concept.

You can try this out in a REPL. First, let's define a method `hello`

```
scala> def hello(s: String) = s"hello $s"
hello: (s: String)String


scala> hello.hashCode
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method hello;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              hello.hashCode
              ^
```

Woops, `hello` is not a value (in the JVM sense)! Not having an hashcode is a proof of it.

Let's get a `Function1` out of the `hello` method

```
scala> hello _
res10: String => String = <function1>    

scala> (hello _).hashCode
res11: Int = 1710358635
```

A function is a value, so it has an hashcode.

Comment: hello is a function already, so why would it use eta-expansion in the second case?

Comment: `hello` is a method, not a function

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was wondering what was the reason behind having two different concepts doing basically the same thing.

Comment: @soulcheck methods predates scala. They exist on the JVM and are full-fledged objects. On the other hand first-class functions are a specific-scala concept, hence the interoperability issues, silently resolved by the compiler with an eta-expansion.

Comment: Yeah it' quite obvious now that I think of it, especially taken into account the java interop. I guess I got used to python, where methods are actually 'bound' functions with the instance as first parameter and that clouded my judgement here.

Comment: Actually they are not scala-specific. They exist in various languages. In scala the trick is that so called functions are classes and compiler silently invokes `apply` method on them. It was already a part of `Google Guava` but there you had to call `apply` explicitly. So biggest secret of scala are actually `implicits`. without them it would lost all its magic.

Comment: @goral, scala-specific w.r.t. to the pre-existing JVM concepts, of course. I'm surely not implying that first-class functions have been invented by scala...

Comment: For world2, the spec doesn't mention eta-expansion. For `world2 { println("Hi, world"); hello }` you wouldn't call it eta-expansion; there is no conversion of method type to function. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters

Comment: @som-snytt interesting. I assumed an eta-expansion since `hello` is a method type, i.e. not a value. Not being a value and not being evaluated beforehand, how can it be passed as the argument of `world2` without an eta-expansion?

Comment: So it does use MethodType (or whatever it uses to represent methods) instead of converting it to function in world2 case?

Comment: A method is not a value, so it definitely cannot be passed as an argument to anything. At this point I'm wondering whether when the parameter is a `=> T` the method is not passed as a function, but simply evaluated via a method call later on.

Comment: @som-snytt so is it passed as function (even if it's a method (?))?

Comment: @EndeNeu, that can't be. Either is eta-expanded or it's not passed as a value.

Comment: Yes, by passed as function I meant, is it eta expanded or not? Since the specs linked by @som-snytt I suppose not, but then how the scala compiler sees `hello` as value, as you pointed out from a JVM perspective, methods are not values.

Comment: You're talking implementation details. A closure is passed that evaluates the whole block or expr. In the closure, it calls hello. That happens to be the same impl as eta-expansion, perhaps, since the expr is only the method call.